# Online Modern Greek dictionary that puts imperfective and ("dependent") perfective verb stems together?

Tags: verbs, greek, dictionary, aspect, online-resources

Does anyone know of a good online Modern Greek dictionary that puts imperfective and perfective (also called "dependent") verb stems together?

For instance, the present perfective of `βλέπω /'vlepo/ "SEE"` is `δω /ðo/`.

However, apparently many dictionaries don't list the two stems together clearly.

Comment: The English Wiktionary does. [**βλέπω** / Greek / Verb / Conjugation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%80%CF%89#Conjugation). The table is folded by default so click on "show" to unfold it. You will find **δω** under Perfective / Dependant / 1st person singular, plus more in a note at the bottom. Wiktionaries are open source and likely to be incomplete until people interested in the languages contribute entries for most of the vocabulary, which of course you are welcome to do yourself.

Comment: In the case of Greek, which has a very ancient indigenous system of grammatical terminology, I do not really see why anyone would want to replace the traditional term “aorist subjunctive” by “perfective dependent”. Especially since the Greek aorist system does not necessarily imply perfective aspect.

Comment: @fdb I don't know why anyone would want to use a term like "perfective dependent" either; That's just the terminology I found on the Wikipedia page, so I assumed it was the most widely used in, iunno, general linguistics or whatever. However, I don't see why anyone would want to use the equally opaque "aorist subjunctive" either. Why not just use terms like "line form" and "point form" mumble grumble... (xD)

Comment: @hippietrail So in order to find out that the "point form" of `λέω` is `πω` (assuming I didn't know either word), I 1) search `en` wiktionary for "say" 2) change to `el` 3) guess that the link I want is probably "

Comment: λέω" and follow it 4) switch back to `en` 5) scroll down and open the conjugation box 6) find the "Dependent" section... I would've thought any English-to-Greek dictionary would just, well, give the "principle parts"?

Comment: @Owen_R: I'm not sure what you mean by "change to `el`". If you mean follow a possible link to the Greek Wiktionary, that's one way. All language dictionaries were developed by separate independent communities so they have different formats and varying coverage, but most dictionaries usually have more coverage of their native language than other languages though the English Wiktionary may have the most non-stub entries across all languages on all Wiktionaries. If you can type or cut&paste the Greek word you can search for it directly.

Comment: ἀόριστος and ὑποτακτική are terms used by Greek grammarians for about 2000 years, and in the English forms “aorist” and “subjunctive” are used to describe all Indo-European languages that have preserved something similar, including the English subjunctive. This is universal linguistic terminology. To ask linguists to abandon it is like asking mathematicians to abandon “triangle” or “calculus”.

Comment: @hippietrail (Sorry, by 'en'/'el' I meant http://en.wiktionary.org and http://el.wiktionary.org ) Anyway, I meant that it surprises me that it apparently isn't standard for *any* Greek dictionary to put all the "principle part" of a verb under the same entry. Is there a tradition of regarding them as "different words" or something?

Comment: @fdb Well, I guess choice of terminology depends on what you're focusing on at the time. If you're interested in historical linguistics within the Indo-European family, terms like "aorist" make sense. If you're interested in functional comparative linguistics (like, "synchronically" or whatevs), then "perfective dependent" might make sense. When you're focused on practical linguistics, terms like "line form" and "point form" are more useful. *shrugs*

Comment: @Owen_R: Sorry I'm more familiar with the English Wiktionary generally than I am with how it deal with Greek specifically, or with the Greek Wiktionary, or with how Greek dictionaries generally work \-:

Comment: Is the example is this question really an example of suppletion, or is it just an example of synonyms?

Comment: @fdb, believe me, if you're trying to analyse how the Modern Greek verbal system works on its own terms, as opposed to as an afterthought of Classical Greek, perfective simplex or perfective dependent is hugely superior to aorist subjunctive. Plus, linguists for the past century have avoided both "subjunctive" and "aorist" for newly described languages like the plague, because they're so tangled up in the histories of specific languages, and not that descriptive to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

As @hippietrail mentioned, Wiktionary does: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/βλέπω#Conjugation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%80%CF%89#Conjugation)

So does the Triantafyllides Institute's dictionary, which is the only one of the three major contemporary dictionaries that's online: [http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/search.html?lq=βλέπω&dq=](http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/search.html?lq=%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%80%CF%89&dq=)

> βλέπω [vlépo] -ομαι (κυρ. στις σημ. I5, II3) Ρ αόρ. είδα, προστ. δες,
>   απαρέμφ. δει και (σπάν.) ιδεί, παθ. αόρ. ειδώθηκα, απαρέμφ. ιδωθεί,
>   μππ. ιδωμένος :

The fact that the perfective simplex δω is not discussed separately from the perfective past είδα and the perfective imperative δες is... regrettable. But yes, Triantafyllides does give principal parts.

Comment: Support the creation of a Greek stackexchange (now in the commitment phase) here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language